# CodeIgniter connection to database

Tags: php, codeigniter

I decided end my cooperation with Doctrine 2.3 and now I would like to make connection to database using only CodeIgniter have you got idea where is problem with my code?

**This Error I get:**

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined property: Hello::$db

Filename: core/Model.php

Line Number: 51
```

**Database.php**

```
$db['default']['hostname'] = 'localhost:8080';
$db['default']['username'] = 'root';
$db['default']['password'] = '';
$db['default']['database'] = 'ci_doctrine';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
```

**Controller**

```
<?php
    // system/application/controllers/hello.php

    class Hello extends CI_Controller {

        public function __construct()
        {
             parent::__construct();
        }
       function world() {
            echo "Hello CodeIgniter!";
        }

        function user_test() {

            $this->load->model('user');

            $this->user->save_User('username','password','first_name','last_name');

       }
}

?>
```

**Model - table name in database "user"**

```
<?php
    // system/application/models/user.php

    class User extends CI_Model {

            function __construct()
            {
                // Call the Model constructor
                parent::__construct();
            }

             function save_User($username,$password,$fName,$lName)  {

                $this->username   = $username; 
                $this->password = $password;
                $this->first_name    = $fName;
                $this->last_name    = $lName;
                $this->db->insert('user', $this);
              }

    }
?>
```

Comment: Are you on localhost? if yes then try removing 8080 post

Comment: @raheel shan but if I will remove this port I`m not able to connect to website. My port 80 have Skype and WAMP have 8080.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to load the database library:

config/autoload.php

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database');
```

Comment: you mean this -> $autoload['config'] = database.php; ??

Comment: yes are you loading database class? you haven't mentioned it in question.

Comment: No I mean $autoload['libraries'] = array('database'); Folder application/config file autoload.php :)

Comment: I get this -> A Database Error Occurred

Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings.

Filename: C:\wamp\www\nauka\system\database\DB_driver.php

Line Number: 124

Comment: Now you have another error on your application/config/database.php file. Change you specs to correct ones, in order to connect to your database.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you are not loading database class

```
$this->load->database();
```

[Here](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/connecting.html) is the Codeigniter User Guide

Without connecting you can not use database class therefore it is saying undefined property db.

Comment: try to free post edit for wamp by going to Skype->tool->settings->advance->connection and uncheck use port 80 and 443 then restart wamp and skype

Answer (score 1):

For manual connection
Use this in your controller file

```
$this->load->database();
```

For automate connection in database

Go to Controller then in autoload.php make the following changes

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database');
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to load the database library:

**config/autoload.php**

```
 $autoload['libraries'] = array('database');
```

Try it .